# Using KVM and VirtualBox VMs concurrently

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I am considering moving several of my virtual machines to a single Linux system for a variety of reasons. The problem is that most VMs are KVM-based, *but* there are a few VirtualBox VMs as well.

I have found several posts ([1](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/virtualbox-and-kvm-installed-at-the-same-time-any-problems-753104/), [2](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15720), [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1618034), [4](http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/03/virtualbox-can-operate-in-vmx-root-mode.html)) that seem to boil down to this: *It is not possible to use VirtualBox when the KVM modules are loaded. Therefore it is not possible to have both VirtualBox and KVM VMs active on the same host.*

Considering that virtualization on Linux is developing at a fast pace, is this still the definitive word on this issue? Are there any workarounds? If not, is the ability to run multiple hypervisors somewhere in the roadmap?

PS1: I do not consider `rmmod kvm` to be a real workaround...

PS2: ...nor using either QEMU/KVM or VirtualBox in software emulation mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt this will ever be possible, and it doesn't make any sense to have two virtualization systems compete over resources and control of the VT-X extension.

Even if this would work, I guess performance would be terrible.

---

Edit: It appears I am wrong and this is indeed possible at least in some cases. As this is a site for professional system administration, this is **NOT** a recommended mode of operation.

Comment: I suppose that on production systems your reasoning is valid - one hypervisor per physical system should be enough. My case is somewhat of a corner case. I ended up moving the server VMs only by migrating them to KVM, although in some cases I had to reinstall the VM when the OS-that-shall-not-be-mentioned did not like the different hardware. I left the desktop VMs alone for the time being...

Comment: It might be possible, but you'd have to be either insane or extremely desperate to even think about doing it. I certainly would not take the risks this sort of Franken-setup would impose.